# How can I cast type using runtime type reflection?

Tags: go, generics, interface

I am trying to build a function using generics, that converts a slice of interfaces into a slice of type T.

I came up with below:

```
func convertInterfaceArray[T any](input []any, res []T) {
    for _, item := range input {
        res = append(res, item.(reflect.TypeOf(res[0])))
    }
}
```

However, this will not compile. But you got the idea. T can be any type and I have an input slice of type []any that needs to be convert to []T

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assert the value to type `T`. Reflection is not required.

```
for _, item := range input {
    res = append(res, item.(T))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/cFn_nsVFIik